# Craft installation fails with SQL error (PostgreSQL)

Tags: installation, craft4, postgresql

I am trying to install the Craft CMS (Version 4.4.1) on a VM in the Azure Cloud with PostgreSQL 13.9 as managed Azure Service.

The error i'm running into is the following:

```
*** failed to install Craft: An error occurred while executing the "craft\migrations\Install migration: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 
ERROR:  null value in column "dateCreated" of relation "info" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 4.4.1, 4.4.0.4, f, jlynfdbhxzhh, junzvyhomsyt, null, null, 0).
The SQL being executed was: 
INSERT INTO "info" ("version", "schemaVersion", "maintenance", "configVersion", "fieldVersion", "id") VALUES ('4.4.1', '4.4.0.4', FALSE, 'jlynfdbhxzhh', 'junzvyhomsyt', 1)
```

Creation of tables, indexes and foreign keys just works fine. But as soon as the `info` table is being populated, the installation crashes with the error above.

The local docker setup installs just fine (configured with PostgreSQL too).

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Hrm... locally, were you using PostgreSQL 13.9 as well? The install migration calls Application::saveInfo, which ultimately calls Command::insert, which inserts the dateCreated, dateUpdated and uid column values if they don't exist: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/db/Command.php#L32-L43

Comment: Thank you @BradBell for your insights. When debugging the Commend::insert method, it turns out that the `dateCreated` checking condition evaluates to `false`. This is because `$this->db->columnExists($table, 'dateCreated')` itself evaluates to `false`. How can that be?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I was able to debug and fix the problem.

The use of a specific schema in the PosgreSQL DB (instead of `public`) caused the problem. But not the fact itself was problematic, instead the schema was missing in the Postgres `search_path`.

Fixing the `search_path` also fixed the problem.

Comment: Ahh... nice debugging and thanks for the follow-up!